# SQL - Avoiding duplicate pairs on a self join/inner join?

Tags: sql, join, duplicates, self

I have database where among other tables I have this one:

```
CREATE TABLE `Physiotherapist`(
`pid` INT,
`name` VARCHAR(40),
`hours` INT,
`cid` INT
```

I want to write an SQL query that returns a list of pairs of physiotherapists that work at the same clinic but will
not return duplicates. My answer so far is:

```
SELECT  p1.name AS name1, p2.name AS name2
FROM    Physiotherapist p1 
INNER JOIN Physiotherapist p2 on p2.cid = p1.cid AND p1.name != p2.name
```

or alternate solution with self join:

```
SELECT  p1.name, p2.name
FROM    Physiotherapist p1, Physiotherapist p2
WHERE   p1.cid = p2.cid AND p1.name !=(SELECT p2.name)
```

Either way I get this result:

```
name1:            name2:

Jan Christensen   Ira Assent
Ira Assent        Jan Christensen
```

I.e. the same pair. I only want one of the duplicates, as they display the same information, but I cannot figure out a convenient way to do it.

EDIT: The full database code with sample data

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Physiotherapist;

CREATE TABLE `Physiotherapist`(
    `pid` INT,
    `name` VARCHAR(40),
    `hours` INT,
    `cid` INT
);

INSERT INTO Physiotherapist VALUES('123','Ira Assent','8','1');
INSERT INTO Physiotherapist VALUES('246','Annika Schmidt','1','2');
INSERT INTO Physiotherapist VALUES('327','Jan Christensen','5','1');
INSERT INTO Physiotherapist(`pid`,`name`) VALUES('455','Simon Winter');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Clinic;

CREATE TABLE `Clinic`(
    `cid` INT,
    `name` VARCHAR(40),
    `address` VARCHAR(40)
);

INSERT INTO Clinic VALUES ('1','PhysCentral','Aarhus C');
INSERT INTO Clinic VALUES ('2','PhysIOgnomy','Aarhus N');
INSERT INTO Clinic VALUES ('3','Physios','Aarhus V');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Appointment;

CREATE TABLE `Appointment`(
    `aid` INT,
    `date` DATE,
    `time` INT,
    `pid` INT
);

INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES(34716,'2018-06-12','10','246');
INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES(23118,'2018-08-18','11','327');
INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES(88223,'2018-10-03','9','246');
```

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific 

versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your 

particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords 

you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, 

using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See 

the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT  p1.name, p2.name
FROM    Physiotherapist p1, Physiotherapist p2
WHERE   p1.cid = p2.cid AND p1.name !=(SELECT p2.name) AND p1.pid > p2.pid
```

This way you should only get one combination from the 2 possible.

Comment: It produces (Jan Christensen - Ira Assent) as the result. Altough, while it does produce what I want, I wonder if its correct answer. But thanks a lot!

Comment: Adding more therapist shows that it does not work, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Simply include pid <> pid (assuming that is the primary key, which it indeed looks like from your definition) as well;

```
SELECT  p1.name AS name1, p2.name AS name2
FROM    Physiotherapist p1 
INNER JOIN Physiotherapist p2 
    on p2.cid = p1.cid 
    AND p1.name != p2.name 
    -- Add this to WHERE
    AND p1.pid != p2.pid
```

Comment: It seems to still produce duplicate pairs in the opposite columns. Tough with it I apparently don't need to check for equivalent names tough.  I appreciator the answer tough, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think below query will work for you

```
select T3.* from 
(select clname,count( distinct pname) from
(SELECT  p1.name as pname,c.name as clname
FROM    Physiotherapist p1 inner join
 Clinic c on p1.cid=c.cid
 ) as T  GROUP BY clname
 having count( distinct pname)>1
) T2 inner join        

 (SELECT  p1.name as pname,c.name as clname
FROM    Physiotherapist p1 inner join
 Clinic c on p1.cid=c.cid
  ) t3 on t2.clname=t3.clname
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cbace/10

Comment: Well, while this seems to produce no duplicates even when I ad more therapists, the problem I am working on asked me to "Write an SQL query that returns a list of pairs of physiotherapists that work at the same clinic. Do
not return duplicates.". I.e. I need them paired. But beautiful work, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you the idea , I have a publications table with authorid and bookid fields.To get the authors who were co-authors in at least a book , my sql query is :

```
SELECT p1.authorid , p2.authorid
FROM publications p1 , publications p2
WHERE p1.bookid = p2.bookid AND p1.authorid<>p2.authorid AND p1.authorid>p2.authorid;
```

Hope you got it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT p1.name, p2.name
FROM    Physiotherapist p1 INNER JOIN Physiotherapist p2
ON  p1.cid = p2.cid AND p1.pid>p2.pid
```

Here we are doing self join using the clinic ID to get pairs, the pid comparison in the where condition avoids duplicate value/pair, then finally we do distinct to get only the distinct pairs.